# Permission denied to get property Window.startLoad

Tags: javascript

All of a sudden, this doesn't work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.opener.startLoad();
self.close();
</script>
```

I get the following from firebug.

```
Permission denied to get property Window.startLoad
[Break on this error] window.opener.startLoad();
```

I am not even sure why it says properly "Window.startLoad" since "startLoad" is a function??

This was working yesterday, the day before and the day before...I am racking my brains why this isn't working any more?

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure both windows are on the same domain? It sounds to me like the child window contains content from a different domain, which won't be allowed to access the parent window properties or functions.

Comment: The window first goes to a different site and the other site redirects back to a page that is on my server. This was working before, for days, it just stopped working today and I can't figure out what I changed. Aarrgh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with local content - if some of the other content (like your javascript startLoad function) is in a different folder (which counts as a different domain) you won't be able to access those functions from your <script>

Did you reinstall Firefox recently, or upgrade to a new version?  One of my coworkers did this, and we had to change one of the permissions in FF to get it to work again.  Type

```
about:config
```

in the address bar, then type

```
fileuri
```

in the **Filter:** textbox.  this should leave you with only the **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** setting remaining. Change it to **false** by double-clicking it, and that should take care of your issue.

Comment: Yes, that function is in a JavaScript folder that is different to the folder that child window is displaying the page from. However, this was working before! No file structure has changed! I don't what it could be though.

Comment: I haven't changed browser, it might have done an autoupdate though.?? I can't expect users to do that to use my site! Maybe there is another way of triggering a function on window close. I think I will ask this as a seperate question.

Comment: This is helpful for developers who are targeting Firefox as one of their browsers - however there's a caveat here. By disabling enforcement of the origin policy, you are opening yourself up to possible XSS attacks while in Firefox, so this should really only be used for developers. Kudos to Scott, though.